# How to query only first letters of name and surname in CONTACTS column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I was asked to query only first letters of name and surname from a column in SQL Server. And the rest should be "*" instead of letters

For example: Waldemar Fisar, should be queried like. W******* F****

Updated question:
I am getting this:

- **John Snow** after query becomes **J S**
- **Lora White** after query becomes **L W**

But need to get:

-**John Snow** should become J*** S***
-**Jonathan Conan** J******* C****

***Lastly, both names and surnames are in the same column***

```
    SELECT 
        Personal info, SUBSTRING([Primary Contact], 1, 1) + ' ' +
                       SUBSTRING([Primary Contact], CHARINDEX(' ', [Primary Contact]) + 1, 1) AS CI 
    FROM 
        xx
```

Comment: T-SQL isn't ideal for this task, if I am honest. You would be better off masking the values *before* you pass them to SQL Server.

Comment: I am in intership. The instructor's task like that. Working on MSSQL.

Comment: What is the *actual* task you were given? Also, if this is homework, then have a read of [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/2029983); us giving you the answer isn't what your instructor asked for, they want **you** to answer the question, not someone else. Though my point stands, T-SQL is a terrible language to do this in. You *could* look at [Dynamic Data Masking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver16), but that doesn't change the values, it just masks for some users.

Comment: [REPLICATE(N'*', 11)](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) gets you `***********`.  [LEN(N'Fisar')](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) gets you `5`. And you can get the first character of a text string with [SUBSTRING(N'Fisar', 1, 1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). That should get you started. The time you spend learning to use your DBMS's string-handling functions will not be wasted.

Comment: If you'd done the sensible thing and kept the names in separate columns then you could simply do `MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(1,"********************",0)')`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function for that task like the example below:

```
create function hide_name(@text nvarchar(max), @ch nchar(1), @n int)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    return LEFT(@text, @n) + REPLICATE(@ch, LEN(@text) - @n)
end

go

SELECT 
dbo.hide_name(yourNameColumn, '*', 1) + ' '  +  dbo.hide_name(yourFamilyNameColumn, '*', 1) 
FROM yourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended, but someone might need

```
declare @Person table (
                          name nvarchar(max),
                          surname nvarchar(max)
                      );

insert into @Person values ('John', 'Snow'), ('Lora', 'White');

select CONCAT(
               IIF(len(name) > 0, concat(LEFT(name, 1), REPLICATE('*', len(name) - 1)), ''),
               IIF(len(name) > 0 and len(surname) > 0, ' ', ''),
               IIF(len(surname) > 0, concat(LEFT(surname, 1), REPLICATE('*', len(name) - 1)), '')
           ) as HiddenName
from @Person
```

Comment: No need to concat. it is already. Names and surnames are in the same column. Just replacing all letters with '*' needed. Apart from first letters of names and surnames.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Personal info, SUBSTRING([Primary Contact], 1, 1) + ' ' +
                   SUBSTRING([Primary Contact], CHARINDEX(' ', [Primary Contact]) + 1, 1) AS CI 
                 , SUBSTRING([Primary Contact], 1, 1) + replicate('*',CHARINDEX(' ', [Primary Contact])-2)
                    + ' ' +
                   SUBSTRING([Primary Contact], CHARINDEX(' ', [Primary Contact]) + 1, 1) 
                   + replicate('*',len([Primary Contact]) - CHARINDEX(' ', [Primary Contact])-1) AS CI_Star  
FROM 
    xx
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure positional solution

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #names
GO
CREATE TABLE #names(thename NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #names(thename)
VALUES
('Alison Arnold'),
('Dorothy Jones'),
('Christopher Mackay'),
('Jason H Paterson'),
('Thomas Johnson'),
('Dave')


SELECT subnames.thename,STRING_AGG(subnames.maskedsubname,' ')
FROM
(
    SELECT
        n.TheName,
        SubNames.SubName,
        LEFT(SubNames.SubName,1)+REPLICATE('*',(LEN(SubNames.SubName)-1))AS MaskedSubName
    FROM #names n
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT Value AS SubName FROM STRING_SPLIT(n.TheName,' ')) SubNames
)subnames
GROUP BY SubNames.SubName
```