# How to replace all letters with '*' apart from first ones in a column which has names and surnames in it in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In this column I was able to only query of the first letters (thanks to a guy from Stackoverflow).

For example:

- `John Snow`  after query becomes `J S`
- `Lora White`  after query becomes `L W`

But I need to replace all remaining letter with `*`

- John Snow        should become  J*** S***
- Jonathan Conan                  J******* C****

This is the code:

```
SELECT 
    Personal info, SUBSTRING([Primary Contact], 1, 1) + ' ' +
                   SUBSTRING([Primary Contact], CHARINDEX(' ', [Primary Contact]) + 1, 1) AS CI 
FROM 
    xx
```

Comment: Use TRANSLATE function

Comment: How does this differ from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73192474/how-to-query-only-first-letters-of-name-and-surname-in-contacts-column-in-sql-se) for which you've neither accepted the answer to or commented on?

Comment: I could not find the answer for which i am looking for on that question. As far as i understand it is is partly answered. So i came back with the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `translate()` function if your version of SQL Server supports it:

```sql
declare @t table (
    Name varchar(100)
);

insert into @t (Name)
values
    ('John Snow');

select t.Name,
    translate(
        t.Name collate Latin1_General_100_CS_AS,
        'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm',
        '**************************'
    ) as [MaskedName]
from @t t;
```

One more thing: the input string needs to be provided with a case-sensitive collation. Depending on which particular collation you use in your system, swap the one in the example above to a suitable case-sensitive one.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, it's a rather cumbersome one for a multi-lingual system. If that's the case, I would resort either to a CLR function, or client-side preprocessing. Also, Dynamic Data Masking might be a suitable solution, but I've never heard a good word about it.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, I mean, I understand why someone would downvote it. It's not very expandable; however, if all their names come with the same codepage, it's the simplest one to implement. Alternatives would require a bit more code, possibly a big bit.

Comment: @RogerWolf  thanks but it works only in 2017 and version of SQL servers but mine i think 2014 version.

Comment: @JavidHesenov, you really should have specified the version of your SQL Server instance, esp. when it's that old. Anyway, with 2014 you are out of luck with this one, and I believe with DDM as well. I would try to upgrade the instance to 2019; barring that, your best bet is probably a CLR function. But that's an area which isn't very familiar to me.